# Breaking journey in UK - two tickets or one?

Tags: trains, uk, tickets

I wish to travel from London to Yeovil Junction but need to break the journey at Basingstoke and stay overnight. Saturday evening London to Basingstoke, Sunday afternoon Basingstoke to Yeovil.

Can I buy one ticket from London to Yeovil and break the journey, or do I need two separate tickets?  It seems much dearer with two separate tickets.

Comment: I assume these are train tickets, not bus?

Comment: Are you looking to book only a single (one way) ticket, or a return? (It'll affect the rules)

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest available ticket that permits overnight break of journey is an Off-Peak Return (*not* an Off-Peak Day Return), costing £58.10.  However, when you break journey overnight you must recommence onward travel before midday the next day, so that wouldn't work in your case.

I'm not sure why you'd think that two separate tickets is dearer - two separate tickets cost £21.60 + £26.80 (Off-Peak + Anytime), which actually works out at less than an Off-Peak Single for your journey (£51.50). The only cheaper tickets are Advance, which tie you to a specific service.